# Spark job location in kubernetes cluster - No such file error

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes

I am trying to submit the Spark application to Kubernetes cluster, the job file is at : /opt/spark/applications/ path, submitting spark using below command:

```
${SPARK_PATH}/bin/spark-submit \
--master <K8S_MASTER> \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-py-driver \
--conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark-py:2.4.0-rc3 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-py-driver \
--conf spark.executor.memory=2g \
--conf spark.driver.memory=2g \
local:///opt/spark/applications/spark_submit_test_job.py
```

Am getting 'No such file or directory' error, though the job file is there at the path on the node.

```
python: can't open file '/opt/spark/applications/spark_submit_test_job.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is your python script inside the docker image which you are using?

Comment: No, its not inside the docker image. Is it required the job script to be present in docker image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the instruction on [spark running on Kubernetes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes#cluster-mode) states:

> Finally, notice that in the above example we specify a jar with a specific URI with a scheme of `local://`. This URI is the location of the example jar that **is already in the Docker image**.

You need to create a correct Dockerfile with the script already present in the image.

A better solution would be using a repository that can be loaded when you are running the image, or instead you can use [Remote Dependencies](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes#dependency-management)